# Chromecast support in PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, chromecast

This topic has been brought up in the past, but figured it's time to bring it to the forefront again. Are there any stable plugins out there to bring Chromecast support to PhoneGap / Cordova? Is a plugin still needed? Would love to get the discussion going again since multi-screen experiences are so huge right now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few plugins available, try them

https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast // Android

https://github.com/AVGP/cordova-chromecast // Android

https://github.com/SesamTV/ChromecastCordova // Android

https://github.com/rbackhouse/chromecast_cordova_plugin // Android

https://github.com/noppolp/wondex-chromecast-cordova // iOS

Comment: Do you know if there are any plugins that also work in ios (none of the ones linked do)

Comment: rbackhouse plugin has ios code on it, I've updated with a new one, ios only

Comment: rbackhouse's plugin has ios code, but they are just empty functions. the ios part is commented out of plugin.xml. I'll have a look at wondex, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

ConnectSDK finally updated their plugin for Cordova, and I can confirm very easy setup and use, and it supports other devices than Chromecast. I can confirm I have streaming support to Chromecast and Amazon Fire TV.

I'm even using Ionic with Cordova, and it worked out of the box. This is my choice, BY FAR, for app to smart tv device. LG and Roku may be working as well, but I have not been able to test yet.

Now I have an excuse to get an Xbox One... another device ConnectSDK claims to support... for "testing."

http://connectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/cordova/setup-instructions/

Comment: As of right now the connecsdk.com domain displays a GoDaddy expired domain page. Ooops. However, they do have a fairly active GitHub account with several interesting looking repos: https://github.com/ConnectSDK

Answer (score 2):

I have been using https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast for a couple of months now on an android project and it seems to work pretty well. The only thing I have found missing is the requestSessionById method.

Comment: It doesn't support ios

Comment: Yeah, I was using it for Android, thanks for the note.