# How to install chromecast in Phonegap build

Tags: jquery, youtube, phonegap-build, chromecast

How can i install chromecast in Phonegap build?
I did'n found any documentation for phonegap build.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into `documentation` related to the `phonegap` build and plugin related.

https://github.com/SesamTV/ChromecastCordova

The above link will help you if you first `setup` the `libs and tools`. It seems the link for setup in the above documentation no long works. Use the below link for setup related to libs and tools.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_setup

Also it would help if you attach any **build** logs.

Comment: How do i install this plugin? For phonegap build i need something like this <plugin name="cordova-plugin-XXXXXXX" source="npm"/>

Answer (score 1):

I don't also see any documentation regarding your concern. However, I have found this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421609/chromecast-support-in-phonegap-cordova) that recommends plugins which you can use for your phonegap project.

> There are a few plugins available, try them
>
> https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast // Android
>
> https://github.com/AVGP/cordova-chromecast // Android
>
> https://github.com/SesamTV/ChromecastCordova // Android
>
> https://github.com/rbackhouse/chromecast_cordova_plugin // Android
>
> https://github.com/noppolp/wondex-chromecast-cordova // iOS

You can also check [ConnectSDK](http://connectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/cordova/setup-instructions/) plugin which supports Chromecast.

Comment: i tried them all. I know myself with phonegap build yet not so good. I get the hole time error messages. I need a documentation or how to for phonegap build :/