# How can we use chrome cast use in ionic 4 for IOS?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, chromecast

I want to implement `chrome-cast` for IOS mobile with `Ionic4`.

I was tried many plugins which I already used but I am facing many issues because Ionic 4 using latest `typescript` version and `chrome-cast` plugins are very old, So many classes and libraries are deprecated.

I've used below links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-cast

https://github.com/jellyfin/cordova-plugin-chromecast

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chromecast

[Chromecast support in PhoneGap / Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421609/chromecast-support-in-phonegap-cordova#answer-29429791)

Please give any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, now I've implemented chrome-cast for IOS in Ionic with the help of this tutorial [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chromecast)

I used this script in podfile

> pod 'google-cast-sdk', '~> 2.0'

And run commands

```
pod install
```

Now it is working fine and I found some issues in this like play and pause but I handled this. If anyone want to know any issue related this. I believe I'll help surely.

Comment: Hi @saddam, how did you implement and does it work for both iOS and Android?

Comment: Hello @saddam, Did you implemented this for Android Also? Is it working with the current version of the ionic?

Comment: Hello @DharmendraKumar , Yes it is working with android also.